# New LWC Edit button not functioning

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, lightning-datatable

I am creating a new LWC datatable with an 'Edit' button.  WHen I click the button, nothing happens.  No error, no actions.  Any assistance is appreciated.
I can confirm that when setting the breakpoint in handleRowAction, it is never reached by the program. Also when I set console.log to activate when button is clicked, nothing happens. It appears that the button is not firing the handleRowAction.

HTML

```html
<template>
     <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
         <lightning-datatable
             key-field="id"
             data={issueLogData}
             show-row-number-column
             hide-checkbox-column
             onrowaction={handleRowAction}
             columns={coulumList}>
     </lightning-datatable>        
    </div>      
</template>
```

JS

```js
 import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
 import lwcAddEditButtonToTable from '@salesforce/apex/lwcAddEditButtonToTable.getIssueLogList';
 import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
     const columns = [
         {
             type:"button",
             fixedWidth: 150,
             typeAttributes: {
                 label: 'Edit',
                 name: 'Edit',
                 variant: 'brand'
             }
         },       
         {label: 'KanbanCard Name', fieldName: 'Lean__KanbanCard__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'IssueLog Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Score', fieldName: 'Lean__Score__c', type: 'Number'},
         {label: 'Weight', fieldName: 'Lean__Weight__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Probability', fieldName: 'Lean__Probability__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Detail', fieldName: 'Lean__Detail__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Resolved', fieldName: 'Lean__Resolved__c', type: 'Boolean'}
     ];
 export default class LwcAddEditButtonToTable extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
   
     issueLogData;
     coulumList = columns;
     error;
  
     @wire(lwcAddEditButtonToTable)
         wiredData({error, data }){
             if (data){
                 console.log('Data \n', data);
                 this.issueLogData = data;
                 this.error = undefined;
             }
             else if (error){
                 console.error('Error:', error);
             }
         }
 
         handleRowAction(event){
             const recId =  event.detail.row.Id;  
             const actionName = event.detail.action.name;  
             
             if ( actionName === 'Edit' )         
                 this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                         type: 'standard__recordPage',
                         attributes: {
                             recordId: recId,
                             // objectApiName: 'Lean__IssueLog__c',
                             actionName: 'edit'
                         }
                     });
                 
                }
         }
```

APEX

```apex
public with sharing class lwcAddEditButtonToTable {
     
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
    public static List<Lean__IssueLog__c> getIssueLogList(String issueId){
        List<Lean__IssueLog__c> issueLogList = new List<Lean__IssueLog__c>();
              
        return [
                SELECT Id,  Lean__KanbanCard__c, Name,  Lean__Score__c, Lean__Weight__c, Lean__Probability__c, Lean__Detail__c, Lean__Resolved__c
                FROM Lean__IssueLog__c
                //WHERE Id = :Id
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by no action? is your `handleRowAction` invoked at the very least? what debugging attempts have you taken?

Comment: In the dev tools of the LWC, there are no errors.  I do not believe my handleRowAction is being invoked. For debugging, I open the dev console, and receive no messages or errors.

Comment: can you confirm? set a breakpoint, or at the very least a console.log and line by line, check where the "bottleneck" might be

Comment: I can confirm that when setting the breakpoint in handleRowAction, it is never reached by the program.  Also when I set console.log to activate when button is clicked, nothing happens.  It appears that the button is not firing the handleRowAction

Comment: thx for checking, mind updating your post?

Comment: I have updated the post.